# How can I delete exactly node in JTree?

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jtree, treenode

I have a tree like this:

```
-root
 -grandParent1
  -parent1
   -child1
   ....
 -grandParent2
  -parent1
   -child1
   ....
```

How can I delete exactly grandParent1-parent1-child1 in database? At first, I distinguish child name with parent, but if parent have same name is problem.

Comment: Post the code you already have. Deleting depends on TreeModel you use.

Comment: Please, clarify your request. Your question title refers to swing control, but you're asking about database. Add example of what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @Andrem Thompson...Thanks, I'm newbie with JTree, i don't don't know the way to work with its. Your answer lead me the way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I distinguish child name with parent, but..

**..should** be identifying them by their entire path (which is unique for every tree node)!

See, for example, [`JTree.getPathForRow(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#getPathForRow-int-)<sup>1</sup> which returns a [`TreePath`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/TreePath.html)<sup>2</sup>.

> 1. Returns the path for the specified row. .."
> 2. `TreePath` represents an array of objects that *uniquely identify* the path to a node in a tree.